# Cant access codeigniter session variable until page refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Am using codeigniter to build an eCommerce site.
I have a method on controller where users enter their delivery information before checkout, the method saves the delivery information and creates a new session variable called "orderid" which has the value of the orderid as its value. After setting the session variable the method redirects to the checkout controller where i retrieve the "orderid" from the session to retrieve the order from the db for the user to confirm the information before paying.

The problem is, when the user is redirected to the checkout page, they dont see their delivery  data.
When do this

```
echo $this->session->userdata('orderid');
```

I can see the value
But when i pass it to my method that supposed to return an array of data

```
$order = $this->orders->get_order($this->session->userdata('orderid'));
print_r($order);
```

I get an empty array `array()`

When the checkout page is refreshed it behaves correctly.
What could be the problem

Comment: Where did you put that `echo` statement? Is it right before the `get_order` method call? I'm kinda guessing that you actually set the value AFTER you call that method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot access session value like this

```
$order = $this->orders->get_order($this->session->userdata('orderid'));
```

You can use the following method it ll be work fine for you

```
$orderid=$this->session->userdata('orderid');
$order = $this->orders->get_order($orderid);
```

***please remembere  load session library at constructor or in this function*

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Comment: Kemal Fadillah  What is the wrong about my code please explain

Answer (score 0):

In order for the session to work you have to add `$this->load->library('session');` to your `__contruct()` function

```
public function __construct() {
parent::__contruct();
$this->load->library('session');
}
```

Comment: -1 Codeigniter doesn't use traditional PHP session. It actually stores it's 'session' data in cookies (or in a database if you have it set up). Therefore, there is no need to add the session_start()